# adding items to list<> from dropdownLsit and displaying them on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am quite a Newbie to asp.net and c#.
I am trying to add some characteristics to a profile by choosing from dropdownList 
and adding to a list<>.

now it works fine but i guess when, click the final show or save button to save the list it dosen't show anything. 
here is my sample code

this goes before Page_Load method.

```
public  List<string> myList = new List<string>();


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    myList.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.Remove(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in myList)
    {
        Label1.Text = item.ToString();
    }
}
```

i guess on button1 click, the item added to myList is for local scope only right? so that's why  i have this problem? Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. When the page is posted back, another instance of your code behind is created and the only things filled in are related to controls on the page which store their data in the ViewState. The easiest way to do what you want is to add another dropdownlist to the page (hidden or not) and add the items to that. This way they will be stored in viewstate and you can keep track of them.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand, you mean add a hidden DropdownList ?? i am confused>

Comment: You already have a dropdownlist with items in it which you want to optionally add or remove from a list. If you add a second one with visible="false" then it won't appear on the page but you can use it as a storage mechanism. Raimond's answer is the full monty but a second dropdown list to store the items you want to add or remove would take less code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the variable myList only 'lives' when the page is called during a postback and after the page has been rendered the variable disappears. What you need is a way to save the value of the variable over two postback calls. This can be done as in the following sample:

```
public List<string> myList
{
   get
   {
      if( ViewState("myList") == null )
      {
        return new List<string>();
      }
      return (List<string>)ViewState("myList") 
   }

   set
   {
        ViewState("myList")  = value;
   }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tmp = myList;
    tmp.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
    myList = tmp;


}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tmp = myList;
    tmp.Remove(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
    myList = tmp;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public  List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

to

```
    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Items"] == null)
                ViewState["Items"] = new List<string>() ;
            return (List<string>)ViewState["Items"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Items"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Change `Button3_Click` event as below

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in myList)
    {
        Label1.Text += item.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @designerNProgrammer you need to change the `Button3_Click` code as well